# Can phpmyadmin localhost:1306 and mysql shell localhost:1308 affect my php mysql combination results?

Tags: php, mysql

Some days ago I changed xampp mysql settings from localhost:1306 to localhost:1308.because my windows was reatructing some features.
Now at this point my php mysql code is not working.And i see phpmyadmin localhost:1308 and mysql shell localhost:1306.
Now my question is that is this the reason i am getting errors in executing php mysql code?and also how can i change mysql shell localhost:1306 to 1308

Comment: Please dont devote it i am stuck in this problem from 2 days npw

Comment: We don't know what code you're running or what errors you're getting, so how can we help you? Please update the question with relevant info

Answer (score -1):

you need to change the port in your php code. like this if you are using mysql_connect

```
mysql_connect('localhost:1308', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
```